# WPF: how to bind to a dictionary item from ContentTemplate of DatagridHeader

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, filtering

I'm trying to implement a filtering popup with combobox on a datagrid header. I'm trying to bind the itemsource of the combobox inside the popup to the content of the related column.

To do this I'm populating a dictionary of observable collections with the property name of the data collected in the grid as key, and up to here everything works properly.

Then I could write the property name that I want to use as key in a textblock inside the popup with the binding and I can write the combobox content if I explicitly use the property name as index of the dictionary in the binding (see first `<LisBox>` element commented declaration).

But when I'm trying to bind the index to the property name I got binding errors.

I hope the code makes clearer what I'm trying to do:

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="Prove_varie.GridWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prove_varie"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="GridWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800"
        x:Name="myWindow">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persone}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="togglePopUp"
                                                  Content="v"
                                                  Width="15"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  BorderThickness="0"
                                                  Background="Transparent"
                                                  Foreground="DarkGray"
                                                  Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                                    <Popup Name="myPopup"
                                           DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=myWindow}"
                                           IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=togglePopUp}">
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <!-- in this textblock i get the property name that I want to use as index -->
                                                <TextBlock Name="myPopupText"
                                                           Background="LightBlue"
                                                           Foreground="Blue"
                                                           Padding="30"
                                                           Text="{Binding Column.Header,
                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                                                Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                                AncestorType=  {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}},
                                                                StringFormat='{}{0}'}">
                                                </TextBlock>

                                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PropertiesDictionary[{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=  {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}},StringFormat='{}{0}'}]}">

                                                <!-- this declaration works but only with static dictionary key name -->
                                                <!--<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference myWindow}, Path=PropertiesDictionary[Name]}">-->
                                                <!--<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference myWindow}, Path=PropertiesDictionary[{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}}]}">-->
                                                <!--<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PropertiesDictionary[{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}}]}">-->
                                                </ListBox>

                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Popup>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using Prove_varie.Mocks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace Prove_varie
{
    public partial class GridWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Persona> Persone { get; }

        public Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<object>> PropertiesDictionary { get; private set; }

        public GridWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Persone = new ObservableCollection<Persona>(new FakeDataProvider().GetData());
            DataContext = this;
            PropertiesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<object>>();

            PropertyInfo[] propArray = typeof(Persona).GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in propArray)
            {
                PropertiesDictionary.Add(prop.Name,
                    new ObservableCollection<object>(Persone.Select(p => prop.GetValue(p)!).Distinct()));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

All suggestions are welcome, even about using completely different approach.

Comment: A Binding within a Binding will never work. The Key of a dictionary in a Binding path in XAML needs to be a literal or a static property or a StaticResource. 
If I were you I'd shape my VMs so that everything I want to bind to in the Column Header lives within 1 VM and I would make that VM the data context of the header.
Inside the header you than have standard binding syntax that directly accesses one property by its name.

Comment: @lidqy thanks, I will try to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Popup* is not a child of the visual tree that the *DatGrid* is a child of.
The *DataGridColumn* and its elements like *DataGridColumnHeader* are not a child of the visual tree. This is why you can't reference elements that are children of the *Window* (or tree root in general).

But you can reference static resources.
For example, you could define a *CollectionViewSource* that binds to your *Dictionary*. Then bind to it using a *MultiBinding*. You have to use a *MultiBinding* because nested *Binding* expressions are not supported:

**DictionaryToValueConverter.cs**

```cs
public class DictionaryToValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return values.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault() is string key
      && values.OfType<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>>().FirstOrDefault() is Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> propertyMap
      && propertyMap.TryGetValue(key, out IEnumerable<object> propertyValues)
        ? propertyValues
        : Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**GridWindow.cs**

```cs
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:DictionaryToValueConverter x:Key="DictionaryToValueConverter" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SourceDictionary"
                          Source="{Binding PropertiesDictionary}" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              <ToggleButton x:Name="togglePopUp"
                            Content="v"
                            Width="15"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Foreground="DarkGray"
                            Margin="5,0,0,0" />
              <Popup Name="myPopup"
                     IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=togglePopUp}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                  <StackPanel>
                    <!-- in this textblock i get the property name that I want to use as index -->
                    <TextBlock Name="myPopupText"
                               Background="LightBlue"
                               Foreground="Blue"
                               Padding="30"
                               Text="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, StringFormat='{}{0}'}" />

                    <ListBox>
                      <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DictionaryToValueConverter}">
                          <Binding Source="{StaticResource SourceDictionary}"
                                   Path="(CollectionView.SourceCollection)" />
                          <Binding ElementName="myPopupText"
                                   Path="Text" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                      </ListBox.ItemsSource>
                    </ListBox>
                  </StackPanel>
                </Border>
              </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Trying your code, if I set a breakpoint on the converter I find that the values item passed as string (the one coming from Text property of myPopupText) is an empty string, whil the Dictionary is passed correctly. I cannot understand what's wrong  because I don't get any error, just the combobox is empty because Dictionary key is empty I guess.

Comment: I guess the TextBlock myPopupText is showing the correct text? You can remove the StringFormat property from the binding, it's redundant. Also note that the Converter is executed two times: first when the Popup is being initialized. At this time the relative source binding e.g. on the TextBlock.Text property won't resolve that's why the Text property returns an empty string for the converter. The second time is when the relative source bindings resolve and the TextBlock.Text value changes. This second run is when you have to inspect the converter parameter values.

Comment: I wonder what ComboBox you are talking about? Your example does not contain nor mention a ComboBox. or have you replaced the ListBox with a ComboBox?

Comment: Sorry, ListBox. Here's quite late.... however you are right the converter is called several times and the latest have the correct key. Anyway to make it work in the converter return statement I had to replace the IEnumerable<> with ObservableCollection<> as per original type declared in code behind. Declaring the PropertiesDictionary as Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<object>> make it work as per your code. Thanks!